# how delete a specific node in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart

I hooked up firebase and made the save data in it. But I can't delete a specific entry in firebase.

I tried deleting through method that I wrote below. But it doesn't work.

```
final FirebaseDatabase _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
delData(String phoneNumber) {_database.reference()
.child('phoneNumber')
.remove()
.then((_) {
    print("Delete $phoneNumber successful");
    setState(() {
      // 
    });
  });
}
```

---

**Update**

the method that I was advised by Frank van Puffelen does not work correctly, it removes all entries with the phoneNumber field, and I need to delete the entry with the phone number under which the user is authorized. In addition, the method listens when new notes are added with the phoneNumber field and deletes them automatically

`````
removeNode() {
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
        .child('customers')
        .orderByChild('phoneNumber')
        .equalTo(phoneNumber)
        .onChildAdded.listen((Event event) {
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
          .child('customers')
          .child(event.snapshot.key)
          .remove();
    }, onError: (Object o) {
      final DatabaseError error = o;
      print('Error: ${error.code} ${error.message}');
    });
  }````
// This is how is i add data to DB     
   ````void handleSubmit() {
      final FormState form = formKey.currentState;
      print(userPhone);
      if (form.validate()) {
        form.save();
        form.reset();
        itemRef.push().set(item.toJson());}````
`````

[image: this is what i want to delete]

Maybe I should use firestore?

Answer (score 4):

In order to delete a node, you need to know the complete path to that node. If you don't know that complete path, you can use a query to determine it.

So in your case, if you know the phone number of the node you want to delete, you can query for all nodes with that phone number (since there may be multiple) and then delete them.

The code for this would look something like:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
  .child('customers')
  .orderByChild('phoneNumber')
  .equalTo('+79644054946')
  .onChildAdded.listen((Event event) {
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
      .child('customers')        
      .child(event.snapshot.key)
      .remove();
  }, onError: (Object o) {
    final DatabaseError error = o;
    print('Error: ${error.code} ${error.message}');
  });
```

---

Update (20200221): You can also use a `once()` listener and loop over its child nodes with:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
  .child('customers')
  .orderByChild('phoneNumber')
  .equalTo('+79644054946')
  .once()
  .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> children = snapshot.value;
    children.forEach((key, value) {
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
        .child('customers')        
        .child(key)
        .remove();
    })
  });
```

Comment: thanks, I tested this code, unfortunately it removes only the line with the phone in firebase, and you need to delete the entire record with the number under which the user is authorized. In addition, your code removes the contents of the variable that stores the phone number.

Comment: I used a hard-coded phone number in my answer so that there is no dependency on a variable that we can't see the value of. The code in my answer removes the direct child node under `/customers` that matches the phone number. If it does something else for you, update your question with the minimal code that reproduces that.

Comment: It looks like what I want to do will not be implemented in firebaseDatabase, I want to use firestore, do not tell me how to adapt my code for firestore?

Comment: Deleting data is not significantly different in Firestore than it is in Realtime Database. There too you will need to run a query to determine the full path to the document to delete. I'm pretty sure the code I shared is what you need to do, so if you're having problems implementing it, update your question to include what you tried based on my answer.

Comment: Your code seems to work correctly, but it removes the phone number in the application to. Please, tell me how to either copy it before deleting (the object, not a link to it), or how to get a phone number from currentUser FirebaseUser, I tried in different ways, it didn't work

Comment: Based on your current question it is impossible to help with your new problem. You might want to post a new question for that, which shows the [minimal way to reproduce this new problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited the question, I don't know what the code even is spread, there is nothing special, only the transmission and display of variables

Comment: Don't try to edit my answer with additional information about your new problem please. As I said, if the code in my answer works correctly (which it will, beyond some potential syntax errors), you should probably open a new question, and accept this one.

Comment: Sorry, I confused your answer with the question itself when editing

Comment: You'll need to have something in the node that you want to delete that uniquely identifies it. If you do, add an `if` inside the `listen` callback to ensure you only delete that node.

Comment: the phone number is unique for each user, how to make a condition with it?

Comment: If the phone number is unique, then the `.equalTo('+79644054946')` in my code will ensure that only the unique node is matched. I highly recommend at this point that you debug the code and see exactly what value you're passing in to the query, and what child nodes are matching that value. The code I shared will not match child nodes that have another phone number.

Answer (score 0):

12 Jan 2022. Work for me.

```
Future<void> delteteNode async {
DataSnapshot event = await database.ref('customers')
   .orderByChild('phoneNumber')
   .equalTo('+79644054946')
   .get();
Map<dynamic, dynamic> children = event.value as Map<dynamic,dynamic>;
children.forEach((key, value) {
database.ref('customers')
   .child(key)
   .remove();
  });
}
```

I don't understand, now 23h PM. I can't use this.
Error: [firebase_database/index-not-defined] Index not defined.
I can't equalTo when i use get. Now i use once .

```
DatabaseEvent event = await database.ref('customers')
.orderByChild('phoneNumber')
.equalTo('+79644054946')
.once();
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> children = event.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
   children.forEach((key, value) {
   database.ref('customers')
  .child(key)
  .remove();
  });
 }
```