# Flutter - Delete data from a specific value, Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

Whenever I try to assemble this query or some similar one that filters through a value I get this error:

Code:

```
final FirebaseDatabase _databaseCustom = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
_database.reference().child("todocustom").orderByChild("todoId").equalTo(todoId).remove();
```

Error:

> "The method 'remove' isn't defined for the class 'Query'.
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'remove'"

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: dose the todoId exists on the database ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56610929/how-delete-a-specific-node-in-firebase/56611004#56611004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call `remove()` on a Query object.  As you can see from the [API documentation for Query](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase/Query-class.html), there is no method called `remove()`.  If you want to delete all the children that would result from a Query, you will actually have to perform that query using [once('value')](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase/Query/once.html), iterate the resulting [DataSnapshots](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase/DataSnapshot-class.html), and call `snapshot.ref.remove()` on each one individually.